# "Invalid command 'Order'" after deleting /etc/apache2

Tags: apt, apache2, dpkg

I'm having a hell of a time setting up a dev environment for Wordpress.

I messed everything up a couple weeks ago and this afternoon wanted to start over.

I tried to reset Apache by uninstalling the package and deleting the /etc/apache2 directory.

Then I reinstalled Apache2 and restored the directory with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2.2-common
```

Localhost navigates to the "It Works!" page, but Apache won't restart, which make me nervous.

I keep getting this error:

```
Syntax error on line 160 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

...fail!

Any ideas? I'm just trying to get up a working LAMP set up.

Comment: Did you look at the log or config file? Please post an excert of the config file at around line 160 and may be the log file at tht time if you still can't find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is unable to restart due to the error in your configuration file. Did you edit `apache2.conf` by hand? Debug your syntax error in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `sudo service apache restart` should start working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Order` directive is provided by the [`mod_authz_host`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) module, and by deleting the `/etc/apache2` directory you've caused it to become inactive. You need to reenable that module.

Deleting the whole directory is not a good way to start over, for two reasons: there are files in there owned by other packages, and because Ubuntu's package manager thinks your changes are intentional. `apt-get install --reinstall` will not clobber your config changes.

If you want to remove a package and all its configuration, the right way to do that is with `dpkg --purge`. Then, when you reinstall the package, you will get back to the default configuration.

Probably the easiest way to recover from here is to purge all the `apache2.2` packages. Then, reinstall `apache2.2`.

(Another course is to use [`dpkg -i --force-confmiss /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2.2-common-*.deb`](https://serverfault.com/q/82801/44697) to just restore missing configuration files, but that may not be enough if deleting the directory also broke some install-time configuration.)